# Does AWS deliver older messages to SQS when subscribed to SNS

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Say, I have a SNS topic, where the producer publishes messages with TTL set to 2 weeks. A new consumer wants to subscribe the SNS topic using their SQS Queue. Will they get all the messages which haven't expired yet (dut to TTL), or will they only get messages that are published after their subscription started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like only messages sent after the subscription started are delivered.